# Count multiple code by multiple date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

```
 Code | Date       
-------------------
 112  | 14-05-2016
 112  | 14-05-2016
 112  | 15-05-2016
 112  | 16-05-2016
 112  | 16-05-2016
 112  | 16-05-2016
 112  | 16-05-2016
```

I want to count the table by date so the result is 3.

**EDIT**

```
 Code | Date       
------------------------
 112  | 14-05-2016 12:03
 112  | 14-05-2016 12:09
 112  | 15-05-2016 12:54
 112  | 16-05-2016 12:06
 112  | 16-05-2016 12:28
 112  | 16-05-2016 12:36
 112  | 16-05-2016 12:37
```

**Second Edit**
     Code | Date
    ------------------------
     112  | 14-05-2016 12:03
     113  | 14-05-2016 12:09
     112  | 15-05-2016 12:54
     112  | 16-05-2016 12:06
     113  | 16-05-2016 12:28
     114  | 16-05-2016 12:36
     112  | 16-05-2016 12:37

I want to count the table by date so the result is 6.

Comment: ok. But maybe you can show what you have tried ?

Comment: simple group by wont help ..?please explain reason for 3

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cast([Date] as date))
FROM mytable `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [Date])
FROM mytable
```

If `Date` field is of type `DATETIME` then you have to cast it to `DATE`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CAST([Date] AS DATE))
FROM mytable
```

This will return the count of *distinct* `Date` values present in your table.

Comment: I'm sorry, my data is lacking. Please see my update

Comment: @JNTX1412 Please check the edit I made.

Comment: How about my second update?